# Avoiding consecutive operators in Bison

Tags: bison

I am trying to write a grammar and I ran into a problem which I reduced to the classical example of arithmetic expressions. The relevant part of my .y file is:

```
%left '+' '-'
%left '*'
%left UNARY
%token UNARY
%token INTEGER
%%
start:  expr {printf("Result: %d\n",$1);}
expr :  INTEGER
     |  '-' expr %prec UNARY  {$$ = -$2;}
     |  expr '+' expr         {$$ = $1 + $3;}
     |  expr '-' expr         {$$ = $1 - $3;}
     |  expr '*' expr         {$$ = $1 * $3;}
     |  '(' expr ')'          {$$ = $2;}
     ;
%%
```

This grammar accepts expressions like "1+-2" and "1+--2", but I would like to exclude consecutive operators. Is there a simple way of doing it without complicating the grammar too much or resorting to some complicated stack manipulation?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a serious suggestion, but if `--` is a token recognized by the lexer but not recognized by the grammar, then when the user types `--` they will get a syntax error.  You could do the same with `+-`, I suppose.  I'm not sure whether you'd want to outlaw `2/-3` and `2 * -3`.  And clearly, you'll allow `-2 + 1`, and addition is commutatative, so it isn't entirely obvious that `1 + -2` shouldn't be allowed.  Does it actually harm you and your grammar?  Your system will be more systematic (easier to predict, use, document) without the petty restriction.

Comment: Yes, I would like to outlaw all consecutive operators. Anyway, your suggestion would allow them when they are separated by spaces: "1-  -2" unless I make the lexer more complicated!

Comment: I suspect your requirement becomes a semantic rule, enforced by code in the actions for the grammar, rather than something enforced by the syntax.  You presumably don't count parentheses as operators.  The other option, I suppose, is to have the lexer remember what it returned last and make it throw some sort of error (return an unrecognized token type, such as `CONSECUTIVE_OPERATORS` if it gets two consecutive operators.  But I'm not convinced it is a good restriction to place on the code.  Orthogonality and all that...

Comment: Yes, there are many ways. That's why I was wondering whether there is a **simple** solution ;-).

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is by splitting the unary operator into a separate production:

```
%left '+' '-'
%left '*'
%nonassoc UNARY
%token INTEGER
%%
start:  expr {printf("Result: %d\n",$1);}
expr :  primary
     |  '-' primary %prec UNARY {$$ = -$2;}
     |  expr '+' expr         {$$ = $1 + $3;}
     |  expr '-' expr         {$$ = $1 - $3;}
     |  expr '*' expr         {$$ = $1 * $3;}
     ;
primary : INTEGER
     |  '(' expr ')'          {$$ = $2;}
     ;
```

This is (partly) converting the precedence rules into 'normal' productions, and then tweaking them to get the effect you want.

Alterantely, if you want to disallow all consecutive operators, and not just the same operator repeated, you can factor out the prefix rule so it can't occur after any other operator:

```
%left '+' '-'
%left '*'
%nonassoc UNARY
%token INTEGER
%%
start:  expr {printf("Result: %d\n",$1);}
expr :  INTEGER
     |  '-' non_unary_expr %prec UNARY      {$$ = -$2;}
     |  expr '+' non_unary_expr             {$$ = $1 + $3;}
     |  expr '-' non_unary_expr             {$$ = $1 - $3;}
     |  expr '*' non_unary_expr             {$$ = $1 * $3;}
     |  '(' expr ')'                        {$$ = $2;}
     ;
non_unary_expr :  INTEGER
     |  non_unary_expr '*' non_unary_expr   {$$ = $1 * $3;}
     |  '(' expr ')'                        {$$ = $2;}
     ;
```

You might be curious as to why binary `+` and `-` are missing from the last rule -- it turns out they are unneeded due to precedence (and if you add them, you'll get a bison warning about them being useless due to conflicts).  Generally, when refactoring like this, I prefer to get rid of all the precedence definitions and instead use separate rules for the precedence levels as that makes what is going on clearer:

```
%token INTEGER
%%
start   : expr { printf("Result: %d\n",$1); }
expr    : term
        | expr '+' non_unary_term { $$ = $1 + $2; }
        | expr '-' non_unary_term { $$ = $1 - $2; }
        ;
term    : factor
        | term '*' non_unary_factor { $$ = $1 * $3; }
        ;
non_unary_term : non_unary_factor
        | non_unary_term '*' non_unary_factor { $$ = $1 * $3; }
        ;
factor  : INTEGER
        | '-' non_unary_factor { $$ = -$2; }
        | '(' expr ')'         { $$ = $2; }
        ;
non_unary_factor : INTEGER
        | '(' expr ')'         { $$ = $2; }
        ;
```

Comment: That will still accept `1+-2` which OP says should be illegal.

Comment: Rici, you're right. However it does not accept "1+--2"; three operators are out!

Comment: @rici: I was under the impression that he wanted to allow that and just disallow consecutive unary `-`

Comment: Thanks! I guess you there is no way to make it simpler. It's interesting though that rewriting the grammar in extended BNF and implementing the parser as a recursive descent parser (left recursion replaced by iteration), it can be done with just three non-terminals and corresponding procedures. Of course the left operators' association is left out of the grammar.